# php validation with now() date and insert time

Tags: php

hi im currently stuck with a php validation, im trying to make the dates test against the
date();  date to make sure the date is current and wont allow any dates thats less than current date()

```
 public function checkDateField($month, $day, $year)
       {
            if (!is_numeric($month) || !is_numeric($day) || !is_numeric($year) || !checkdate($month, $day, $year)) {
                $msg = '*Invalid date';


// then some where here test the value 
of $month $day $year >= date... 
something like that?
///           
            }
            return $msg;    
       }
```

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. What's your question?

Comment: `checkdate($month, $day, $year) > time()`

Comment: i have to test the $month $day $year against the current Now() date and make sure that it is greater or it sends the invaliddate

Comment: Yeah. I read this thing 4 times, slow and I still don't see the question. From my knowledge "now()" is a MySQL function, yet I don't see any references too it. Perhaps you could mean the "time()"? Edit: Ok

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the datetime diff function to compare your date with now() : http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (*assumes date in the format* `YYYY-MM-DD`):

```
function isValidFutureDate($date)
{
    if (false === strtotime($date))
    {
        return false;
    }

    list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $date);
    if (false === checkdate($month, $day, $year))
    {
        return false
    }

    $now = new DateTime();
    $compare = new DateTime($date);
    if ($compare < $now)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this isn't what you're looking for. Care to explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function checkDateField($month, $day, $year){

    if (!is_numeric($month) || !is_numeric($day) || !is_numeric($year) return 'Invalid date';

    if (strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' 23:59:59') < time()){
        return 'Invalid time';
    }

}
```